# iOS: change @"\r\n\u4f60\u5f00\u4ec0" to right string

Tags: ios, encoding

I get the NSString @"\r\n\u4f60\u5f00\u4ec0\u4e48\u73a9\u7b11\u554a\u7b2c\u4e00 \u6211\u7684\u811a\u8fd8\u6ca1\u6709\u590d\u539f" from web server. And I know this isn't the right string. Maybe something about encoding is wrong. I want to change that string to right string.

Comment: It's Unicode for Han characters.  Find a [Unicode chart](http://unicode.org/charts/) and look up the characters.

Comment: Ah, I think I see now -- You at some point erroneously created that string using `stringWithFormat:@"%@"`, and that converted the legit Unicode representation into a character Unicode representation.  (They will appear to be identical, unless you examine the hex bytes.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just open python interpreter, input "print u'\r\n\u4f60\u5f00\u4ec0\u4e48\u73a9\u7b11\u554a\u7b2c\u4e00 \u6211\u7684\u811a\u8fd8\u6ca1\u6709\u590d\u539f' ".

The output is "

你开什么玩笑啊第一 我的脚还没有复原"

Comment: Thank you, but I need to parse this in iOS.

Comment: @HanPengbo - You don't need to parse it.  It's already a legit NSString.  It just prints that way in debug, should display properly in a text field.

Comment: Google translates the above as "Are you kidding ah first my feet have not restored"..

Answer (score -1):

I find this works well.

```
    - (NSString *)replaceUnicode:(NSString *)unicodeStr
{
    NSString *tempStr1 = [unicodeStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\u"withString:@"\\U"];
    NSString *tempStr2 = [tempStr1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
    NSString *tempStr3 = [[@"\"" stringByAppendingString:tempStr2] stringByAppendingString:@"\""];
                          NSData *tempData = [tempStr3 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                          NSString* returnStr = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:tempData
                                                                                 mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                                           format:NULL
                                                                                 errorDescription:NULL];
    return [returnStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\r\\n"withString:@"\n"];
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do??  There's no property list in that string.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, but it can translate unicode to right Chinese string.

Comment: It doesn't need to translate it.  It's already valid Unicode.